# concatenar um link em um Map

Tags: array, dart, flutter

Recebo dados de uma API do *The Movie DB*, da qual devo pegar um link de imagem,o poster do filme. O problema é que o dado dessa imagem só me gera metade do link.

Codigo:

```
class FilmePresentation extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map _FilmeData;
  FilmePresentation(this._FilmeData);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var link = ["http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/"];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_FilmeData["title"]),
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: Image.network(_FilmeData["poster_path"]),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

perceba que tentei criar uma variável "link" que possui a primeira parte do link e o vetor ["poster_path"] contém a segunda parte. Porém, tentei os seguintes meios e não consigo concatenar:

```
_FilmeData+link+["poster_path"] //ou
_FilmeData[link]["poster_path"] //ou
_FilmeData+"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/"+["poster_path"]
```

existe algum meio de colocar esse link na do ["poster_path"]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, algumas questões a serem esclarecidas primeiro.

Você tem uma variável do tipo `Map` `_FilmeData` (não é o ideal nomear variáveis iniciando com letra maiúscula) e uma variável do tipo `List` link.
Todos os 3 exemplos que você mostrou de tentativas, eu acredito que nem irão compilar, pois você está misturando as coisas.

A variável link poderia ser simplismente uma `String`, não? Ao invés de ser uma lista para guardar um valor.
Dessa forma você poderia simplismente utilizar interpolação de strings para concatenar os valores das urls.

```dart
final _filmeData = {'poster_path': 'segundaParteURL'};
final linkString = 'http://primeiraParte/';
print('Interpolação de String: $linkString${_filmeData['poster_path']}');
```

- > Interpolação de String: http://primeiraParte/segundaParteURL

Caso você por algum outro motivo realmente necessite utilizar uma lista para guardar um valor, você precisa informar o índice
do valor para acessá-lo e pegar a url, ficando:

```dart
final _filmeData = {'poster_path': 'segundaParteURL'};
final linkList = ['http://primeiraParte/']; //Porque usar list??
print('Interpolação de String com List: ${linkList[0]}${_filmeData['poster_path']}');
```

- > Interpolação de String com List: http://primeiraParte/segundaParteURL

Agora, se você precisa atualizar também o valor da url no Map, teria que atualizar ele, fazendo:

```dart
final _filmeData = {'poster_path': 'segundaParteURL'};
_filmeData['poster_path'] = linkList[0] + _filmeData['poster_path'];
print('Substituindo no Map: ${_filmeData['poster_path']}');
```

- > Substituindo no Map: http://primeiraParte/segundaParteURL

Teste esses exemplos no [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/66d5d87865b08eb451b940d48ae6ee5e).

o/

Comment: Meu amigo vc tá de parabéns

Comment: @LucasPires se foi útil, marque a resposta como aceita :)